# NG8002: Can't bind to 'iconDisplay' since it isn't a known property of 'p-calendar'

Tags: angular, primeng-calendar

Getting this error when using [iconDisplay] in p-calendar

i should not get this error, the expected result is calendar icon should show without backgroundcolor and border. Tried updating to newest version of primeng but still the error exists, it blocks other component to loading. Below is the component as per primeng documentation
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="date2" [iconDisplay]="'input'" [showIcon]="true" inputId="icondisplay">

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.